# How to get items added together from cart_items table

Tags: mysql

`cart_items` table structure

```
CREATE TABLE cart_items (
  id BIGINT,
  cart_id BIGINT,
  product_id BIGINT,
  variant_id BIGINT,
  quantity INT,
  product_title VARCHAR(255),
  variant_title VARCHAR(255),
  title TEXT,
  sku VARCHAR(255),
  vendor VARCHAR(255),
  handle TEXT,
  product_type VARCHAR(255));
```

`cart_items` data sample:

```
+--------+---------+---------------+----------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
|   id   | cart_id |  product_id   |   variant_id   | quantity |      product_title       | variant_title |              title              |        sku         |     vendor      |         handle          |    product_type    |
+--------+---------+---------------+----------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| 604311 |   89579 | 1351129989203 | 12543456673875 |        1 | 650C 45mm Micro Wheelset | Orange        | 650C 45mm Micro Wheelset-Orange | Orange Wheels 650c | Pure Fix Cycles | 650c-micro-wheelset     | Wheelsets          |
| 604312 |   89579 | 1351127924819 | 12543450251347 |        1 | Zulu                     | 50 cm         | Zulu - 50 cm                    | The Zulu - Small   | Pure Fix Cycles | the-zulu-glow-fixie     | Glow Series        |
| 612607 |   89558 | 1351129989203 | 12543456673875 |        1 | 650C 45mm Micro Wheelset | Orange        | 650C 45mm Micro Wheelset-Orange | Orange Wheels 650c | Pure Fix Cycles | 650c-micro-wheelset     | Wheelsets          |
| 612608 |   89558 | 1351127859283 | 12543449989203 |        1 | X-Ray                    | 43 cm*        | X-Ray - 43 cm*                  | The Micro X-Ray    | Pure Fix Cycles | cream-and-celeste-fixie | Fixed Gear Bicycle |
| 612609 |   89558 | 1351127924819 | 12543450251347 |        1 | Zulu                     | 50 cm         | Zulu - 50 cm                    | The Zulu - Small   | Pure Fix Cycles | the-zulu-glow-fixie     | Glow Series        |
+--------+---------+---------------+----------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
```

I need to know which items are added together in different carts. According to my example data, the output should be something similar to following:

**Products**

**Zulu** + **650C 45mm Micro Wheelset** are in 2 carts

**Zulu** + **650C 45mm Micro Wheelset** + **X-Ray** is in 1 cart

**Zulu** + **X-Ray** is in 1 cart

I would want to use as much as of mysql query.

Comment: You ask "how to get" but you didn't mention with what. Using a MySQL query or from a program/ web? If using MySQL query, can you post what query have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to do it MYSQL query. I couldn't think of anything so far.

Comment: In my opinion, to get that expected output, you need to make your product combination unique, which I think is a problem because in your example you only show 3 products. That translate to 4 combination in total which is small but what if you have 10 products?